# Sometime App Crashing NSAttributedString Converting HTML to Attributed String

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

Rarely crashing app when converting html to attributed string.

````
var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Any crashlog when happening?

Comment: Unrelated to your crash, but it makes no sense to declare the variable as `Optional<NSAttributedString>` if you never actually return `nil`, but return an empty String instead.

Answer (score 0):

> The HTML importer should not be called from a background thread (that
>   is, the options dictionary includes NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute
>   with a value of NSHTMLTextDocumentType).

It will try to synchronize with the main thread, fail, and time out. Calling it from the main thread works (but can still time out if the HTML contains references to external resources, which should be avoided at all costs). The HTML import mechanism is meant for implementing something like markdown (that is, text styles, colors, and so on), not for general HTML import.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while using Down to convert markdown to NSAttributedString in a UIViewRepresentable.

My solution was to wrap the down.toAttributedString() call in a DispatchQueue.main.async block.

Might not be the cleanest solution. But its the only thing I found that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You set and convert first in your empty string. But you must process that in `onAppear` using `DispatchQueue` . After that, you call the variable `string` that you created before in your code like a below.

**In your properties**

```
@State private var newTitle : String = ""
```

**In your code add below if you use SwiftUI**

```
.onAppear{
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
          newTitle = article.title.htmlToAttributedString
      }
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this work around.
 1. Create an extension of Data class like this.
 [image]

2. and another extension of String class.

   [image]

   3. Call the extension using like this, print("(stringName.html2String)")

Comment: what is difference in my code and this one?? except extension for data was added?